# Running multiple C programs from a C program under Linux

Tags: c, linux, process, execute

I'm trying to learn a bit or 2 about process communication under Linux, so I wrote 2 simple C programs that communicate with each other.

However, it's a bit annoying to have to run them manually every single time, so I'd like to know is there a way to make a program that will run them both, something like this:

```
./runner program1 program2
```

I'm using latest Ubuntu and Bash shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

run.sh script

```
#!/bin/sh
./program1 & 
./program2 &
```

run command:

```
$sh run.sh
```

Answer (score 4):

This line will do (in Bash):

```
program1 & program2 &
```

If you want to record the output:

```
program1 >output1.txt & program2 >output.txt &
```

If you want to run the commands in two separate terminals:

```
xterm -e program1 & xterm -e program2 &
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use this:

```
./program1;./program2
```

or

```
./program1 &;./program2 &
```

I don't know why somebody thinks it's not useful,but it really works.

Surely you can write a script,but what's the content of the script?Still the same thing.

And you can change it at once with no need to open the script first.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a shell script to do what you want -- you don't need to use a C program to run a C program.

Answer (score 0):

Do do exactly what you asked, first created a file called `runner` which will be the shell script.

```
#!/bin/bash

for arg in $@
do
$arg & 
done
```

`$@` in bash is an array of all the arguments passed to the script, this makes the script no restricted to only launching 2 programs. *Note any programs your launch with this scripts need to be on the* `$PATH` or passed to the script as `./program1`.

```
./runner ./program1 program2
```

In the example `program1` is not on the `$PATH` but `program2` is.